# how to send csv file from postman- post request- to CherryPy

Tags: postman, form-data, python-3.8

i have post request to my python code. in the json body I need to send 1 parameter. and then I need to upload csv file.
I have 2 questions: 1. how to upload the csv from postman side 2. how to get it in my python code.
attached my post request and my python code.
[post request screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHMxu.png)

my code in python.

```
    @cherrypy.tools.json_in()
    @cherrypy.tools.json_out()
    @cherrypy.tools.accept(media='application/json')
    def POST(self):
        body = cherrypy.request.json
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use JSON to upload data. You need to convert csv file in to base64 string before you post your data. Because JSON format does not support file.

If you just want to get your data, you can select "form-data" in postman.

Code for 'form-data':

```
import cherrypy


@cherrypy.expose
@cherrypy.tools.json_out()
def uploadcsv(self, img=None, other=None):
    print(img)
    print(other)
    return 'ok'

cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld())
```

Image of postman setting:
[image]